# jQuery or Javascript: Convert from ISO-8859-1 to utf8

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, utf-8, character-encoding

one API that I have to use returns the text using ISO-88951-1, so the words with spanish accents like "obtendrá" are wrong codified when I show them to the user (the valid output would be "obtendrá").

How can I transform the text to UTF-8? I need a function in javascript or jQuery to perfom this conversion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieve what I need using:

```
$("<div>").html(theTextinHex).text();
```

Thanks anyway!

Comment: If possible , can illuminate process , `theTextinHex` ? Thanks

Comment: theTextInHex is a text codified with chars in hexademial, for example "Zurr&#xF3;n"

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple of modules on npm that let you do encoding conversions: [iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv) (requires compilation) and [iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) (doesn't require compilation).